# How do you solve an equation with variable exponents on both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’ve been absolutely stumped on this question. It wants me to ALGEBRAICALLY solve for
$$4000(0.97)^x = 2500(1.05)^x$$
so no graphs. I believe that a logarithm approach should be used for the problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Approaches to solve it? (etc.)

Comment: @Parcly Taxel probably using logarithms

Comment: What happens when you take $\ln$ of both sides?

Answer (score 3):

$$4000(0.97)^x=2500(1.05)^x$$
Divide to reduce the multipliers on both sides:
$$8(0.97)^x=5(1.05)^x$$
Then take logarithms to any convenient base and use logarithmic rules to convert both sides into linear functions of $x$:
$$\log8+x\log0.97=\log5+x\log1.05$$
Thus, manipulating for $x$:
$$x=\frac{\log8-\log5}{\log1.05-\log0.97}=\frac{\log\frac85}{\log\frac{105}{97}}$$
This last expression is equivalent to $\log_{105/97}\frac85$ by the change-of-base relation, showing that the initial choice of base for $\log$ was indeed arbitrary.